# How to declare std::invoke_result of std::bind in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to declare `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter, which binds some arguments to the specific function:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
using HandleDeleter = std::invoke_result_t<std::bind, _1, SOME_FLAG>; // !!!
using HandlePtr = std::unique_ptr<handle_t, HandleDeleter>;

void handle_destroy(handle_t *, int flags);
handle_t * raw_handle;

auto deleter = std::bind(handle_destroy, _1, SOME_FLAG);
HandlePtr ptr(raw_handle, deleter);
```

And this doesn't work because `std::bind` is a monstrous template construction on its own with unspecified return type.

How to properly declare `HandleDeleter` in my case?

Comment: Why cannot you just declare `HandleDeleter` as a `struct` and construct it with as many flags as you want?

Answer (score 3):

`std::bind` is not a single callable, but a function-template. Thus, you would have to choose which one to pass to `std::invoke_result_t`, which is really messy.

Fortunately, there are better alternatives:

1. Use `decltype`:

   ```
   using deleter_t = decltype(std::bind(handle_destroy, _1, SOME_FLAG));
   ```
2. Use template-argument-deduction for the class:

   ```
   unique_ptr ptr(raw_handle, deleter);
   ```

Anyway, not using `std::bind()` is generally simpler, as well as more efficient due to hard-coding the function and argument used. Though you certainly are free to only hard-code part:

1. Use a lambda instead of `std::bind()`. In C++20 a stateless lambda will even become default-constructible:

   ```
   auto deleter = [](handle_t* p){ handle_destroy(p, SOME_FLAG); };
   ```
2. Define your own custom deleter-class instead of using `std::bind`:

   ```
   struct deleter_t {
       constexpr void operator()(handle_t* p) const noexcept {
           handle_destroy(p, SOME_FLAG);
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 2):

> And this doesn't work because `std::bind` is a monstrous template construction on its own with unspecified return type.

This is a hint: you're probably using the wrong tool for the job.

I would use a simple `struct` instead:

```
struct HandleDeleter
{
    int _flag;
    void operator()(handle_t* h) const
    {
        handle_destroy(h, _flag);
    }
};

HandlePtr ptr(raw_handle, HandleDeleter{SOME_FLAG});
```

---

`std::bind` is not recommended in Modern C++. Use lambdas (or structs) instead. `std::bind` has several issues [excellently explained in this talk by Stephan T. Lavavej **“functional: What's New, And Proper Usage"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0).

[image: screenshot from talk]